# Unable to communicate with my chrome extension's javascript file after bundling my extension with webpack

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I tried using firebase on my chrome extension for authentication, and I was getting error regarding

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

After searching, I was told that I will need to bundle my app to be able to use import statement

On installing webpack, configuring and running npm run build, my `service_worker` and content script lost communication with my `popup.js` file. all messages sent into the file do nothing.

Here is my webpack.config.js settings

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // The entry point file described above
  entry:{
    background: './background.js',
    content: './index.js'
  },
  // The location of the build folder described above
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  // Optional and for development only. This provides the ability to
  // map the built code back to the original source format when debugging.
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
};
```

index.html link to javascript file

```
<script src="./dist/content.js"></script>
```

Please what am I doing wrong? this is my first time to both using webpack and configuring chrome extension.

NOTE: my index.html is declared as `web_accessible_resource` file and injected into the webpage using `iframe`. just to give more context to the question.

Comment: Where are you using the import statement? If it's in the service worker, you need to include the service worker as an ES Module. See [Register the service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/#manifest)

Comment: Replace `eval-source-map` with `inline-source-map`. See also [how to debug SW registration](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/gIES818ESgg/m/5U6PEkSPAQAJ) in ManifestV3.

Comment: @thomas-mueller i am importing it in my popup.js file. not service worker.

Comment: @wOxxOm, alright, will try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I was able to resolve the problem.

I added both my `popup.js` and `background.js` file to the entry object of my `webpack.config.js` and replace the original file path with the path to the compiled files. my files now look like this

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  entry: {
    background: './background.js',
    index: './index.js',
  },
  //...
```

`manifest.json`

```
   //...
   "background": {
    "service_worker":"./dist/background.bundle.js" //path to webpack bundled service worker file
  },
  //...
```

`index.html`

```
<script src="./dist/index.bundle.js"></script> <!--path to bundled popup javascript file--->
```